# "Too many redirects" depending on internet provider

Tags: redirect, ip, hosting

The url which it is about: https://www.example.com/ 
Calling domain example.com via adress line in browser causes:

**Case 1**: German internet provider A 
"Too many redirects" 
and 
redirect to http://www.example.com/

But at the same time at

**Case 2**: German internet provider B 
the page is shown without any issues
and
redirect to https://www.example.com/ as intended

This question is in general: How this can happen? Atm i am not able to understand how a page is delivered by one provider without problems but the other provider just delivers "too many redirects". Is there some kind of provider caching?

- It is not browser caching as i got some people who could reproduce this issue with mobile devices of different internetproviders
- As far as i know there was made a change of a redirect entry in backend of hoster via a tool similar to plesk without using a .htaccess file directly. But this has been more than 24h ago.
- Both internet providers are big players with millions of customers

Answer (score 0):

Looked like it was a problem with ipv4 vs ipv6.
My hoster initially delivered the page via ipv6 plus optional ipv4. After changing this by hoster to ipv4 without ipv6 both providers are delivering the page as expected now.

I would appreciate it if anyone has an answer with more technicial details, thx.